# Git: created new branch from a wrong branch

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I usually create new branch from develop

```
git checkout -b new-feature develop
```

then after the last commit I merge back to develop

```
git checkout develop
git merge new-feature
```

but this time I created `new-feature2` brach from `new-feature` and now I cannot merge to `develop`.

Is there a way to switch `new-feature2`'s parent to `develop`?

(The files I worked on were the same version as in `develop` so this should not require merging.)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

> Note: Be sure to have a clean workspace before you begin. Read all messages git shows you. If in doubt, read more about the topic before starting.

You could rebase your feature over to the main base:

```
git checkout new-feature2  
git rebase --onto develop new-feature new-feature2
# rebase the stuff from new-feature to new-feature2 onto develop branch
```

or do it 'manually' by using cherry pick

```
git checkout develop
git log --oneline new-feature..new-feature2 
# for every commit call:
git cherry-pick <commit-id> # note, newer versions of cherry-pick allow multiple commits at once
```

Comment: I already solved the issue with patching, but this sounds more like what I was looking for. Thanks for including the commands, this will help readers. (PS: Note that the branch I wanted to rebase to was `develop`. The example says `maser`.)

Comment: I've changed the example, thanks for pointing that out hakunin.

Comment: Excellent! This preserves commit history, as opposed to the patch approach.

Comment: may God bless you for this answer.

Comment: I ran the `rebase` command and lost all changed done in `new-feature2`.... You didn't warn this would happen if work was already done on that branch ‎

Answer (score 28):

Have you seen interactive rebase?

```
git rebase -i develop
```

is a pretty simple solution–it'll show all your commits from that branch. Just delete the "pick" lines from the unwanted branch.

Comment: IMO, the best solution because you do not need to create a new branch, which would be a nuisance when working with deep integration, like with JIRA

Comment: That was super easy and quick.

Answer (score 4):

what about creating a patch, checkout to the `develop` branch and apply the patch?

```
git checkout new-feature2

git format-patch new-feature

git checkout develop

git am name-of-the-patch.patch
```

Comment: If commit history is important to you, consider the `rebase --onto` technique instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `git diff` and `git apply`:

```
git diff new-feature..new-feature2 | git apply -
```

Comment: Thanks for including an alternative solution!