# Developed a new feature off of the wrong branch and pushed branch to remote

Tags: git, rebase

This question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428587/git-created-new-branch-from-a-wrong-branch) but I need to understand how the complications of having pushed the new feature to remote.

Essentially I have a branch, `new_feature_2`, which I by mistake started developing off of `new_feature_1`. I meant to develop `new_feature_2` off of `main` and now I am trying to rectify my mistake.

From the above link it seems like I should rebase `new_feature_2` onto `main` in the following fashion.

```
git checkout new_feature_2  
git rebase --onto main new_feature_1 new_feature_2
```

Now, I would like to extend the question by understanding what I need to do to the remote branch? I had already pushed my new_feature_2 branch to the remote. Is there anything special I need to do here? Or after I complete the rebase, can I just push again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I had already pushed my new_feature_2 branch to the remote

That's the problem. This now a pushed branch. In some sense, it is a shared branch. But in a larger sense, it isn't! So there's no objection to what you will have to do, which is push with force.

You don't need the initial checkout if you're going to use the full form of `rebase` like that (which you should should definitely use). So

```
git rebase --onto main new_feature_1 new_feature_2
git push -f origin @
```

Done! (By the way, I left out a possible step; you might want to say `git fetch origin main:main` beforehand, just to make sure your `main` is as up to date as it can be before the rebase.)

Comment: Oh thanks for that possible step update! Fortunately my main branch was already up to date with remote (phew).

Comment: This is a bit of an aside but say as I am working on `new_feature_1`, I realize that it could really benefit from the changes made in `new_feature_2` but I don't want to wait for `new_feature_1` to finish code review and merge into main.. Would it make sense to rebase `new_feature_1` onto `new_feature_2`? Or would a merge be more appropriate?

Comment: Depends on your remote milieu. GitHub can certainly deal with a PR that depends on (branches from the end of) another PR.